# If A1 Equals B1 condition

Tags: google-sheets, comparison, formula, equals

- Cell A1 = "YES"
- Cell B1 = "YES"

Is it possible to write a formula that makes Cell C1 EQUAL TRUE if Cell A1 MATCHES Cell B1?

It's a super simple thing I'm trying to do, but I can't find anything useful in the Google Sheets documentation. I know this is possible in MS Excel.

Comment: what about `=A1=B1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can actually just put =eq(A1,B1)  and the default values are true or false.

Or if you prefer a different response you can make it an if statement and choose your own text i.e.

=if(eq(A1,B1),"Yes","No")

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(EQ(A1, B1), TRUE, FALSE) )
```

Comment: This doesn't do the same as asked in the question though as it doesn't compare A1 to B1 but A2 to C2.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Edited the solution to fit the question.